# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Default'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am getting a Value Error, when fitting Logistic Regression model onto Corporate Default dataset.
Error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Default'
```

Can someone advise the reason for such an error and how to resolve it?
Here is my code for reference.

```
features = data_select_new.drop('Default', axis=1)
df['Label'] = 'Default'

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(features, df['Label'], test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: You have a value in either `X_train` or `Y_train` that is the string `"Default"`.  You need to clean your data.

Comment: What is `data_select_new`?  type, dtype if applicable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`df['Label']= 'Default'` creates a column with 'Default' on each row.
As you You probably want to predict the column 'Default' from the original daset, you can write instead:

```
df['Label'] = data_select_new['Default']
```

Comment: I think you're right!